# Postgres performance

Tags: python, django, postgresql, twisted, postgis

I need a help on postgresql performance

I have configured my postgresql files for tuning my server, however it is slow and cpu resources are higher than 120%

I have no idea on how to solve this issue, I was trying to search more info on google but is not enough, I also have try autovacuum sentences and reindex db, but it continues being slow

My app is a gps listener that insert more than 6000 records per minutes using a tcp server developed on python twisted, where there is no problems, the problem is when I try to follow the gps devices on a map on a relatime, I am doing queries each 6 seconds to my database from my django app, for request last position using a stored procedure, but the query get slow on more than 50 devices and cpu start to using more than 120% of its resources

Django App connect the postgres database directly, and tcp listener server for the devices connect database on threaded way using pgbouncer, I have not using my django web app on pgbouncer cause I don't want to crash gps devices connection on the pgbouncer

I hoe you could help on get a better performance

I am attaching my store procedure, my conf files and my cpu, memory information

**Stored procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gps_get_live_location (
    _imeis varchar(8)
)
RETURNS TABLE (
    imei varchar,
    device_id integer,
    date_time_process timestamp with time zone, 
    latitude double precision, 
    longitude double precision, 
    course smallint, 
    speed smallint, 
    mileage integer,
    gps_signal smallint,
    gsm_signal smallint,
    alarm_status boolean,
    gsm_status boolean,
    vehicle_status boolean,
    alarm_over_speed boolean,
    other text,
    address varchar
) AS $func$
DECLARE 
    arr varchar[];
BEGIN
    arr := regexp_split_to_array(_imeis, E'\\s+');
    FOR i IN 1..array_length(arr, 1) LOOP
        RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT 
        gpstracking_device_tracks.imei,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.device_id, 
        gpstracking_device_tracks.date_time_process,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.latitude,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.longitude,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.course,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.speed,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.mileage,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.gps_signal,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.gsm_signal,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.alarm_status,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.gps_status,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.vehicle_status,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.alarm_over_speed,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.other,
        gpstracking_device_tracks.address
        FROM gpstracking_device_tracks
        WHERE gpstracking_device_tracks.imei = arr[i]::VARCHAR
        AND gpstracking_device_tracks.date_time_process >= date_trunc('hour', now()) 
        AND gpstracking_device_tracks.date_time_process <= NOW()
        ORDER BY gpstracking_device_tracks.date_time_process DESC
        LIMIT 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$func$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

**$ cat less /etc/sysctl.conf**

```
kernel.shmmax = 6871947673
kernel.shmall = 6871947673
fs.file-max = 4194304
```

**$ cat /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf**

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main'         # use data in another directory
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf'       # host-based authentication file
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_ident.conf'   # ident configuration file
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/9.1-main.pid'          # write an extra PID file
listen_addresses = 'localhost'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 80                    # (change requires restart)
superuser_reserved_connections = 3      # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql'           # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour
#bonjour_name = ''                      # defaults to the computer name
ssl = true                              # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ciphers = 'ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH'      # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_renegotiation_limit = 512MB        # amount of data between renegotiations
#password_encryption = on
#db_user_namespace = off
#krb_server_keyfile = ''
#krb_srvname = 'postgres'               # (Kerberos only)
#krb_caseins_users = off
#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0                # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0            # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0               # TCP_KEEPCNT;
# shared_buffers = 4096MB                       # min 128kB
temp_buffers = 16MB                     # min 800kB
# work_mem = 80MB                               # min 64kB
# maintenance_work_mem = 2048MB         # min 1MB
max_stack_depth = 4MB                   # min 100kB
#max_files_per_process = 1000           # min 25
#vacuum_cost_delay = 0ms                # 0-100 milliseconds
#vacuum_cost_page_hit = 1               # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_miss = 10             # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 20            # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_limit = 200                # 1-10000 credits
#bgwriter_delay = 200ms                 # 10-10000ms between rounds
#bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 100            # 0-1000 max buffers written/round
#bgwriter_lru_multiplier = 2.0          # 0-10.0 multipler on buffers scanned/round
#effective_io_concurrency = 1           # 1-1000. 0 disables prefetching
#wal_level = minimal                    # minimal, archive, or hot_standby
#fsync = on                             # turns forced synchronization on or off
#synchronous_commit = on                # synchronization level; on, off, or local
#wal_sync_method = fsync                # the default is the first option
#full_page_writes = on                  # recover from partial page writes
#wal_buffers = -1                       # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
#wal_writer_delay = 200ms               # 1-10000 milliseconds
#commit_delay = 0                       # range 0-100000, in microseconds
#commit_siblings = 5                    # range 1-1000
# checkpoint_segments = 64              # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each
checkpoint_timeout = 5min               # range 30s-1h
# checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5    # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
#checkpoint_warning = 30s               # 0 disables
#archive_mode = off             # allows archiving to be done
#archive_command = ''           # command to use to archive a logfile segment
#archive_timeout = 0            # force a logfile segment switch after this
#max_wal_senders = 0            # max number of walsender processes
#wal_sender_delay = 1s          # walsender cycle time, 1-10000 milliseconds
#wal_keep_segments = 0          # in logfile segments, 16MB each; 0 disables
#vacuum_defer_cleanup_age = 0   # number of xacts by which cleanup is delayed
#replication_timeout = 60s      # in milliseconds; 0 disables
#synchronous_standby_names = '' # standby servers that provide sync rep
#hot_standby = off                      # "on" allows queries during recovery
#max_standby_archive_delay = 30s        # max delay before canceling queries
#max_standby_streaming_delay = 30s      # max delay before canceling queries
#wal_receiver_status_interval = 10s     # send replies at least this often
#hot_standby_feedback = off             # send info from standby to prevent
#enable_bitmapscan = on
#enable_hashagg = on
#enable_hashjoin = on
#enable_indexscan = on
#enable_material = on
#enable_mergejoin = on
#enable_nestloop = on
#enable_seqscan = on
#enable_sort = on
#enable_tidscan = on
#seq_page_cost = 1.0                    # measured on an arbitrary scale
#random_page_cost = 4.0                 # same scale as above
cpu_tuple_cost = 0.01                   # same scale as above
cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.005            # same scale as above
#cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025             # same scale as above
# effective_cache_size = 8192MB
#geqo = on
#geqo_threshold = 12
#geqo_effort = 5                        # range 1-10
#geqo_pool_size = 0                     # selects default based on effort
#geqo_generations = 0                   # selects default based on effort
#geqo_selection_bias = 2.0              # range 1.5-2.0
#geqo_seed = 0.0                        # range 0.0-1.0
#default_statistics_target = 100        # range 1-10000
#constraint_exclusion = partition       # on, off, or partition
#cursor_tuple_fraction = 0.1            # range 0.0-1.0
#from_collapse_limit = 8
#join_collapse_limit = 8                # 1 disables collapsing of explicit
#log_destination = 'stderr'             # Valid values are combinations of
#logging_collector = off                # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
#log_directory = 'pg_log'               # directory where log files are written,
#log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'        # log file name pattern,
#log_file_mode = 0600                   # creation mode for log files,
#log_truncate_on_rotation = off         # If on, an existing log file with the
#log_rotation_age = 1d                  # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
#log_rotation_size = 10MB               # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'
#silent_mode = off                      # Run server silently.
#client_min_messages = notice           # values in order of decreasing detail:
#log_min_messages = warning             # values in order of decreasing detail:
#log_min_error_statement = error        # values in order of decreasing detail:
#log_min_duration_statement = -1        # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
#debug_print_parse = off
#debug_print_rewritten = off
#debug_print_plan = off
#debug_pretty_print = on
#log_checkpoints = off
#log_connections = off
#log_disconnections = off
#log_duration = off
#log_error_verbosity = default          # terse, default, or verbose messages
#log_hostname = off
log_line_prefix = '%t '                 # special values:
#log_lock_waits = off                   # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
#log_statement = 'none'                 # none, ddl, mod, all
#log_temp_files = -1                    # log temporary files equal or larger
#log_timezone = '(defaults to server environment setting)'
#track_activities = on
#track_counts = on
#track_functions = none                 # none, pl, all
#track_activity_query_size = 1024       # (change requires restart)
#update_process_title = on
#stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'
#log_parser_stats = off
#log_planner_stats = off
#log_executor_stats = off
#log_statement_stats = off
#autovacuum = on                        # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'
#log_autovacuum_min_duration = -1       # -1 disables, 0 logs all actions and
#autovacuum_max_workers = 3             # max number of autovacuum subprocesses
#autovacuum_naptime = 1min              # time between autovacuum runs
#autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50       # min number of row updates before
#autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50      # min number of row updates before
#autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2   # fraction of table size before vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1  # fraction of table size before analyze
#autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000  # maximum XID age before forced vacuum
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20ms    # default vacuum cost delay for
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1      # default vacuum cost limit for
#search_path = '"$user",public'         # schema names
#default_tablespace = ''                # a tablespace name, '' uses the default
#temp_tablespaces = ''                  # a list of tablespace names, '' uses
#check_function_bodies = on
#default_transaction_isolation = 'read committed'
#default_transaction_read_only = off
#default_transaction_deferrable = off
#session_replication_role = 'origin'
#statement_timeout = 0                  # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#vacuum_freeze_min_age = 50000000
#vacuum_freeze_table_age = 150000000
#bytea_output = 'hex'                   # hex, escape
#xmlbinary = 'base64'
#xmloption = 'content'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
#intervalstyle = 'postgres'
#timezone = '(defaults to server environment setting)'
#timezone_abbreviations = 'Default'     # Select the set of available time zone
#extra_float_digits = 0                 # min -15, max 3
#client_encoding = sql_ascii            # actually, defaults to database
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'                     # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'                     # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'                      # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'                         # locale for time formatting
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
#dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'
#local_preload_libraries = ''
#deadlock_timeout = 1s
#max_locks_per_transaction = 64         # min 10
#max_pred_locks_per_transaction = 64    # min 10
#array_nulls = on
#backslash_quote = safe_encoding        # on, off, or safe_encoding
#default_with_oids = off
#escape_string_warning = on
#lo_compat_privileges = off
#quote_all_identifiers = off
#sql_inheritance = on
#standard_conforming_strings = on
#synchronize_seqscans = on
#transform_null_equals = off
#exit_on_error = off                            # terminate session on any error?
#restart_after_crash = on                       # reinitialize after backend crash?
#custom_variable_classes = ''           # list of custom variable class names
default_statistics_target = 50 # pgtune wizard 2013-09-24
maintenance_work_mem = 960MB # pgtune wizard 2013-09-24
constraint_exclusion = on # pgtune wizard 2013-09-24
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9 # pgtune wizard 2013-09-24
effective_cache_size = 11GB # pgtune wizard 2013-09-24
work_mem = 96MB # pgtune wizard 2013-09-24
wal_buffers = 8MB # pgtune wizard 2013-09-24
checkpoint_segments = 16 # pgtune wizard 2013-09-24
shared_buffers = 3840MB # pgtune wizard 2013-09-24
```

**$ cat /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini**

```
[databases]
anfitrion = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=**** user=**** password=**** client_encoding=UNICODE datestyle=ISO connect_query='SELECT 1'

[pgbouncer]
logfile = /var/log/postgresql/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/postgresql/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = 127.0.0.1
listen_port = 6432
unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql
auth_type = trust
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
;admin_users = user2, someadmin, otheradmin
;stats_users = stats, root
pool_mode = statement
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL
;ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
;server_check_query = select 1
;server_check_delay = 30
; total number of clients that can connect
max_client_conn = 1000
default_pool_size = 80
;reserve_pool_size = 5
;reserve_pool_timeout = 3
;log_connections = 1
;log_disconnections = 1
;log_pooler_errors = 1
;server_round_robin = 0
;server_lifetime = 1200
;server_idle_timeout = 60
;server_connect_timeout = 15
;server_login_retry = 15
;query_timeout = 0
;query_wait_timeout = 0
;client_idle_timeout = 0
;client_login_timeout = 60
;autodb_idle_timeout = 3600
;pkt_buf = 2048
;listen_backlog = 128
;tcp_defer_accept = 0
;tcp_socket_buffer = 0
;tcp_keepalive = 1
;tcp_keepcnt = 0
;tcp_keepidle = 0
;tcp_keepintvl = 0
;dns_max_ttl = 15
;dns_zone_check_period = 0
```

**$ free -h**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G        11G       4.1G         0B       263M        10G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.2G        14G
Swap:          30G         0B        30G
```

**$ cat /proc/cpuinfo**

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 V2 @ 3.10GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x15
cpu MHz         : 3101.000
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips        : 6186.05
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 V2 @ 3.10GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x15
cpu MHz         : 3101.000
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips        : 6185.65
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 V2 @ 3.10GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x15
cpu MHz         : 3101.000
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips        : 6185.66
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: 96MB workmem seems very high, when you have several users you certainly cannot ensure each one can take several times 96Mb to perform sort operations and such (80 conn means 7.5 Go of RAM at least). And you should give us the index available on gpstracking_device_tracks

Comment: Can you add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query in the function?

Comment: BTW do you have an index on `gpstracking_device_tracks.date_time_process` ?

Comment: I have solve until now the problem, and yes I also think is too much, but I am not a dba, I just apply my knowledge as coder for try to understand that and some pg tunning pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR i IN 1..array_length(arr, 1) LOOP
```

**Never** do this. Your stored procedure just iteratively builds up result set. In fact, you are running one query for **each** of the target devices. Instead, use `ANY` + `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
arr := regexp_split_to_array(_imeis, E'\\s+');
RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dt.imei ORDER BY dt.date_time_process DESC) as rnumber
        --other fields here
        FROM gpstracking_device_tracks dt --added alias
        WHERE dt.imei = ANY(arr)
        AND dt.date_time_process >= date_trunc('hour', now()) 
        AND dt.date_time_process <= NOW()
    )
    where rnumber = 1
```

I don't have Postgres and your database at hand to verify correctness of the solution, but I think you should be able to debug it to the point where it is. At least, it's a direction to follow.

Refer to [window functions docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) and [row and array comparisons docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparisons.html) for details.

To improve the responsiveness even more, consider fetching location updates only. So, instead of fetching all the history each 6 seconds, fetch it once at page load/app init/whatever, than poll the server for *updates* only. Inner query would look something like:

```
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dt.imei ORDER BY dt.date_time_process DESC) as rnumber
        --other fields here
    FROM gpstracking_device_tracks dt --added alias
    WHERE dt.imei = ANY(arr)
    AND dt.date_time_process >= @last_poll_timestamp
    AND dt.date_time_process <= NOW()
```

Comment: I am trying on it, but rnumber is not usable on where clause that makes me a error

Comment: The simplest way to fix it is to wrap it into an embracing select and apply `where rnumber=1` to the outer select, like this: `select * from (query goes here) where rnumber=1`. But I'm quite not sure about the performance of such approach. Updated the answer.

Comment: I choosen it as answer cause the response increases really well

Comment: @J0HN To fetch first record in every group postgres `DISTINCT ON` can be faster than `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: DatabaseError at /tracking/positions/request_live/
column "last_poll_timestamp" does not exist
LINE 39: ...D gpstracking_device_tracks.date_time_process >= @last_poll_...

Comment: I have tried the last one edition, however it gives me an error

Comment: @last_poll_timestamp is a new parameter to the function. Should contain timestamp of last update.

Comment: @JhON, I will do a dumb question. How to populate this last parameter

Comment: Add it to function's parameter list, and pass it all the way down from webpage. I.e. webpage -> service -> data access layer -> database